# Отправка на сервер кода 200 не используя return

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Имеется вебсервер для приема POST, данный сервер часть огромного конвеера который выполняется 5+ минут взависимости от приходящего POST
Из-за этого FLASK возвращает 500 код, как это можно исправить?

КОД FLASK

```
@app.route("/gitlab-webhook", methods=['POST'])
def githubWebhook():
    def load_secret(TOKEN, key):
        try:
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'I LOAD JSON')
            print(TOKEN, ' !!! ', key)
            if TOKEN == key:
                return 200
            else:
                return 404
        except Exception as e:
            slack_message_pipe(step=e)
    try:
        content = request.json
        data = request.headers
        print(type(data))
        key = data['X-Gitlab-Token']
        load_secret(TOKEN, key)
        commits_list = content['commits']
        json_dump_for_proj(data=commits_list)
    except Exception as e:
        slack_message_pipe(step=e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8889)
```

ОШИБКА:

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /gitlab-webhook [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1535, in finalize_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1698, in make_response
raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function for 'githubWebhook' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
"POST /gitlab-webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Прочитав ошибку, появилась мысль использовать make_response(), но я не нашел пока примеров или что-о из чтива на этот счет

Comment: Добавьте в конце метода `return ""`

Comment: Сделать асинхронную обработку: через POST ставите задание, сервер добавляет его в очередь обработки, и сразу возвращает код 201. В фоне задания из очереди обрабатываются. Далее клиент периодически запросами проверяет статус. Ну или через вебсокеты держать соединение, чтобы сервер сам сообщил, когда все готово.

Comment: @insolor, не совсем понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: @Miekrif на сервере в фоне постоянно должен крутиться бесконечный цикл (процесс/поток), который проверяет наличие задач в очереди. Он запускается при старте сервера, не зависит напрямую от запросов на сервер (только через очередь). Когда в очереди появляется задача, он "забирает" ее, начинает обрабатывать - это то, что у вас сейчас выполняется 5 минут. Результат куда-то сохраняет (в другую очередь, но так, чтобы по id задачи в первой очереди можно было найти результат во второй очереди). Как эти очереди реализовать - это другой вопрос, это могут быть таблицы в базе данных, например.

Comment: При добавлении задачи задача только добавляется в очередь и сразу возвращается ее идентификатор (чтобы по нему можно было получить результат). Ожидания самого результата тут не должно быть.

Comment: Еще, посмотрите в сторону celery, он как раз для подобных задач

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воплотил идею @insolor, но решил не мудрить
Вышло это

```
@app.route("/gitlab-webhook", methods=['POST'])
    def githubWebhook():
        my_resp = ''
        def load_secret(TOKEN, key):
            try:
                # slack_message_pipe(step=f'I LOAD JSON')
                print(TOKEN, ' !!! ', key)
                if TOKEN == key:
                    my_resp = 200
                    return my_resp
                else:
                    my_resp = 404
                    return my_resp
            except Exception as e:
                slack_message_pipe(step=e)
        try:
            content = request.json
            data = request.headers
            print(type(data))
            key = data['X-Gitlab-Token']
            load_secret(TOKEN, key)
            commits_list = content['commits']
            thread = Thread(target=json_dump_for_proj, args=(commits_list))
            thread.start()
            return my_resp
        except Exception as e:
            slack_message_pipe(step=e)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8889)
```